# php mysql prepared statement pass 0 into decimal column where NULLs are allowed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a Mysql table with a decimal column that allows `NULL`s. If I pass 0 as double in a PHP's prepared statement, my 0 turns NULL in the Mysql column.

How can I get the value 0 instead of `NULL`?

PS: I use the following code to insert the value

```
$query2 = "insert into TableName
    (Id, anotherId, date,
    `MinValue`, `MaxValue`,
    `oneMoreId`, `Comment`)
  values
    (?, ?, '2016-06-23',
    ?, ?,
    ?, ?)";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query2);
$stmt->bind_param('iiddis', $Id, $anotherId,
        $minValue, $maxValue, $oneMoreId,
        $comment);
$stmt->execute();
```

EDIT: after answer by @YourCommonSense, I figured there was an error in my code. Above the lines that I posted, I had a change of value from 0 to `NULL`. My fault, sorry, guys!

Comment: You could test for a `0` value and encapsulate `0` with single quotes prior to execution...`$value===0 ? '$value' : $value` etc ~ that should allow entry of zero rather than NULL

Comment: yep, did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I pass 0 as double in a PHP's prepared statement, my 0 turns NULL in the Mysql column.

This is not true.

If you pass 0, then it gets stored as 0.
But if you pass NULL, then it gets stored as NULL.

Therefore, you are passing NULL value, not 0.
Check your values and cast them if necessary.

Comment: man, you rock! i had a change of value from 0 to NULL before in my code. thanks very much. ps: i'm a fan of yours actually after reading your phpdelusions :)